# Can firewall block packets visible in Wireshark?

Tags: firewall, wireshark, windows-firewall

Wireshark shows that an RTP package is received on a PC.

Is it possible that despite detection by Wireshark, something (firewall?) is still prevent the application listening to the required port on that PC to receive the package?

Example.  Wireshark trace shows a recieved RTP(h264) packet, but there is no video on the softphone because firewall is blocking the port.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered a few times already. http://superuser.com/questions/101525/wireshark-and-windows-firewall

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Wireshark operates "before" firewall and sees all the packets that the network card receives. Then the packets get filtered by the firewall running on the PC.